# How to set JetBrains to always use ECMAScript 6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, settings, jetbrains-ide

Not sure why, but even after setting my **Default Settings** AND Project Settings to use `Javascript` -> `ECMAScript 6`, when I relaunch Jetbrains it always falls back to `ECMAScript 5.1`.

[image]

Is there a way to set this setting permanently once and for all?

## Other Notes:

- Version: IntelliJ Ultimate 14.
- OS: Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Notice that *For current project* label. This kind of options should be set in Default settings.

Comment: I've tried this already (bolded in the question now).

Comment: Default Settings affect new projects, project settings are used for current project only. Anyway, both options should persist on restart; Must be a problem saving your settings. I'd suggest creating a support ticket

Comment: @lena deleting the `.idea`folder and re-opening the project folder to recreate it works! If you want to write up an answer with these instructions I will gladly accepted it. I haven't tried **estus**'s solution but I think yours gets rid of this issue with less effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be a problem saving your project settings, may be as a result of .idea files corruption. Try deleting your project .idea folder and re-opening the project directory via File/Open

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug that should be reported to JetBrains.

Any way, it is possible to check it and modify manually in [settings folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/project-and-ide-settings.html#d1653838e183).

In `config/project.default.xml`, these may be settings for ES5.1:

```
<application>
  <component name="ProjectManager">
    <defaultProject>
      ...
      <component name="JavaScriptLibraryMappings">
        <includedPredefinedLibrary name="Node.js Core" />
      </component>
      <component name="JavaScriptSettings">
        <option name="languageLevel" value="ES5" />
      </component>
      ...
```

And these ones are for ES6:

```
<application>
  <component name="ProjectManager">
    <defaultProject>
      ...
      <component name="JavaScriptLibraryMappings">
        <includedPredefinedLibrary name="ECMAScript 6" />
        <includedPredefinedLibrary name="Node.js Core" />
      </component>
      <component name="JavaScriptSettings">
        <option name="languageLevel" value="ES6" />
      </component>
      ...
```

It is preferable to do this when JetBrains product doesn't run.